# Fuerchten vs Befuerchten

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Looking up the usage of these words on [reverso](https://www.reverso.net/text-translation#sl=eng&tl=ger&text=fuerchten%250A%250Abefuerchten) seems they are quite similar. I found this [italki thread](https://www.italki.com/nl/post/question-76499), but it only seems to add in my confusion since it has two seemingly conflicting answers.

Could someone explain how the usage of these two words differ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably talking about point [1a on Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/f%C3%BCrchten?useskin=vector).

> Ich befürchte/fürchte, ich verliere meinen Job.

Both are fine and means the practically the same. You're using it like as a verb of saying in this one - indicated by the Verbzweitnebensatz "ich verliere meinen Job".

In any other usage, they are not similar at all. Please see the Wiktionary link for all its uses.
For example:

- *fürchten* can be used for people in two usages, but *befürchten* can not.
- *fürchten* is used reflexively in one usage, but *befürchten* is never used reflexively.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, *fürchten* is a bit more universal, since it can **directly** refer to somebody or something (provided by an accusative object):

> - Kinder fürchten die Dunkelheit.
> - Ich fürchte mich.

*Befürchten* is typically applied to a situation, which follows e. g. by an auxiliary clause.

> Ich befürchte, dass die Bankenkrise anhält.